# Custom conversion to grayscale MATLAB

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I have an image such as the one below that I am trying to convert to grayscale. However, I do not want the standard conversion to grayscale.

Ideally I would like to define some custom color map that would convert the image to grayscale based on the values in the map.

For example: I would like to convert the image below to grayscale using the "jet" gradient in

Visit http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/121/673/121673915_640.jpg

Comment: you can find the mapping function of jet in jet.m in your matlab directory. or type "edit jet" in command window; once you have that you can apply/edit the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

Here is the [algorithm used by Matlab's built-in method *rgb2gray()*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html):

> *rgb2gray()* converts RGB values to grayscale values by forming a weighted sum of the R, G, and B components:
>
> 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
>
> Note that these are the same weights used by the *rgb2ntsc* function to compute the Y component.

Note that we have a single multiplier for each of the color channels, which makes life easy.

**Solution**

The inverse mapping is a nonlinear problem- there is no single set of RGB weights that can take you from the colors back to the gray. You also have no guarantee that the `jet` colormap contains all the colors used in the image.

Here is a best-effort workaround, which maps colors to the nearest color in the colormap:

```
%% Define the transformation as a non-uniform 3D interpolation
resolution = 512;
cmap = jet(resolution);
x = cmap(:,1);
y = cmap(:,2);
z = cmap(:,3);
intensity = gray(resolution);
intensity = intensity(:,1);
fx = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z,intensity,'nearest');

%% Load our image, then interpolate from RGB to Grayscale intensity
img = double(imread('image.jpeg'))/255.0;
imgOut = fx(img(:,:,1),img(:,:,2),img(:,:,3)); 
imshow(imgOut)
```

Runtime is a function of colormap resolution, *resolution=512* takes about a minute, *resolution=64* takes about 5 seconds. This is slow for two reasons.  First, we are doing a non-linear search for each pixel (rather than applying a linear transform).  Second, the interpolation is scattered (rather than uniformly defined) which further slows things down.

**Input**

[image: Input image]

**Output with colormap resolution = 64**

[image: Output with colormap resolution = 64]

**Output with colormap resolution = 512**

[image: Output with colormap resolution = 512]